# Puedo programar en IOS 10 con una MAC antigua

Tags: ios, macos

Hola tengo una MacBook 13-inch, Mid 2010

- Procesador 2.4 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
- Memory 2 GB 1067 MHz DDR3

Verifique en la AppStore y encontré que puedo actualizar el sistema macOS Sierra y xcode 8, aun no intento actualizarlo, **¿La RAM y el Procesador me va funcionar para crear una aplicación y publicarla en el AppStore?**

Comment: Por poder puedes con Xcode 8, pero con esas características de ordenador te diría que ni lo intentes. Lo mismo te tarda unos 15 minutos cada vez que le des a compilar. Yo tenia uno similar al tuyo con 4 de ram y termine por comprar otro

Answer (score 1):

No hace falta tener macOS Sierra para programar en iOS 10. Solo con poder instalar el Xcode 8 alcanza.

Eso si, puede ser que los tiempos de compilación sean bastante grandes, y hay que ver si la computadora soporta el emulador. Lo recomendable seria que no uses el emulador sino que conectes un iPhone, así le ahorras recursos a la MacBook.

Answer (score 0):

Para programar para IOS 10 requiere la ultima versión de IOS y la ultima versión de XCode, de todas formas si lo soporta ira todo muy muy lento.

He intentado con un MacMini de estas características y al final he tenido que ampliar la RAM, le he puesto 10GB y de paso le he puesto un SSD de 500Gb.

Ahora va de maravilla.